# MongoDB check connection of replica member before connecting with Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am implementing a feature in Java to check the status of the replica set. To do that, I have to connect to one member of the replica set. I extracted the information of each replica set from mongos and stored them in an array, from that array I can get the uri of all replica members.  The problem is that I don't know how to detect if that uri works or not before connecting to it. Currently, I am doing this:

```
MongoClient shard = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(
                new ServerAddress(replicaUriTemp[0]),
                new ServerAddress(replicaUriTemp[1]),
                new ServerAddress(replicaUriTemp[2])));
```

When I stop two replica members [0] and [1], the program cannot connect to [2] and perform the replSetGetStatus command. It always throws this exception:

```
MongoTimeoutException: A server error occurred: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=dockerbox:21100, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}, {address=dockerbox:21200, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}, {address=dockerbox:21300, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, roundTripTime=1.0 ms, state=CONNECTED}]
```

However, it works fine when I try to connect to replica member [2] directly:

```
MongoClient shard = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(replicaUriTemp[2]));
```

Is there a way to resolve this matter by connecting to each replica member dynamically, or ping the member before attempting to connect to it ?  I want to blindly test status of replica set without knowing in advance which one is primary/secondary member.

**Edit:** Seems like the error appears in the my next line of code:

```
Document replStatus = shard.getDatabase("admin").runCommand(replStatCmd);
```

Since I turn off two replica members, the left one will become a secondary and that's why I cannot perform runCommand on this member.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after I set the option runCommand to ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred(), the program works fine now.